# Create a File object representing a directory relative to the root of a .jar file

Tags: java, file, executable-jar, robolectric

I'm trying to run Robolectric tests that are kicked off inside of an executable .jar file. [Robolectric requires](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/customizing.html) you to pass a File to its constructor with the directory which contains the AndroidManifest.xml file. My AndroidManifest.xml file sits at the root of my .jar file, and the test runner lives in a package something like com.some.package. How can I achieve this?

I tried the following:

```
public class CustomTestRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner {
    public CustomTestRunner(Class testClass) throws InitializationError, URISyntaxException {
        super(testClass, new File(CustomTestRunner.class.getResource("/AndroidManifest.xml").getPath().replace("AndroidManifest.xml", "")));
    }
}
```

Which doesn't work, when it runs Robolectric complains, and I get this FileNotFoundException:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /Users/christopherperry/Desktop/file:/Users/christopherperry/Desktop/my-executable-jar.jar!/AndroidManifest.xml
>   not found or not a file; it should point to your project's
>   AndroidManifest.xml at
>   com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricConfig.validate(RobolectricConfig.java:73)
>     at
>   com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.createResourceLoader(RobolectricTestRunner.java:602)

I don't understand because the AndroidManifest.xml file IS in the root of the jar file, and from the error message this appears to be where it is looking.

Answer (score 0):

Items in JAR files are not themselves files, so the answer is "you can't".

You can access them via URLs obtained from Class.getResource(), or streams obtained from Class.getResourceAsStream().

Comment: @ChristopherPerry JAR files are not file systems. You can't write to them, if that was your intention, without completely rebuilding the. Rethink your requirement.

Comment: I'm not trying to write to a jar, re-read my problem. Robolectric is trying to read a file packaged inside of the jar. That is Robolectric's requirement, not mine.